# Engineering a better solution, coming from existing codebase

Tags: rewrite, refactoring

**The Code**

I have high-business-value daily-used-by-customer software that is written in PHP and spans approximately 600K lines of code.

Customer for a long time needs, wants, and demands new features and functionality.  The time to have it done is *yesterday*.  So, just write the new features and implement new functionality and deliver it to the customer, yes?  Well, no, here are some problems that have been causing considerable pain to current developers:

**Existing code-base is ... a [big ball of mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud).**

Notable problems:

- code is hairy - a single feature permeates everything, tracing code is a pain, and adding a feature may potentially impact everything else
- there are no tests
- mix of procedural and object oriented code ridden in bad programming practices
- files reaching 6000-lines of HTML, CSS, PHP, SQL, jQuery, JavaScript, comments
- complete disregard/non-existence of MVC/separation-of-concerns pattern. Code is intermixed together
- some business logic depends on volatile things that have no relation to the code (like database metadata)
- hardcoded values, paths, and lack of configurability contribute to lack of security of current architecture
- large repeated blocks of essentially the same code contribute to similar features working slightly differently.  Updating one does not update the other
- code is slow, lack of documentation., etc, etc.  quite a few other things can be done better

**It works...**

The good thing is that it works...  The functionality that's there, is reasonably worked-out for actual business cases, but ... going forwards is painful.

**The Problem**

It is easier now (and faster) to add a new feature using existing code style, mostly using cut-n-paste-n-modify approach, thus perpetuating the badness, than it is to do rewrites of this thing using currently existing modern best practices.

**Solution?**

There is a talk about rewriting the whole thing using one of the currently-leading frameworks (i.e. ZF2), but in doing so it means ignoring customer demands, taking a long time to build the software, and essentially creating new software (version 0.0.1) for the customer, with all the new-software bugs and lack of mature-software feel and functionality.

Another thought is to do some incremental development.  i.e. When a new feature comes about, write it using a new approach.  This is currently failing for the reason stated under "The Problem" title above.

Yet another idea is to do some slow refactoring of existing codebase... It might work in cleaning up things like MVC and a host of other things, and it will take a long time, and it will essentially feel like unraveling a messed up tightly-wound knotted ball of yarn.  But doing this will not address things like unit testing, dependency injection, modern framework principles, and so on.

So, in the end, new features are coming, code is being added, and the existing codebase is not getting any better.  What might you suggest to do in this case?

Comment: Please use the search function (key words "Legacy" and "Ball of Mud" come to mind), this has to be the most commonly asked and answered question .

Comment: the answers and linked questions are great in theory.  I am facing a more specific situation, now trying to decide whether to port the application to ZF2 or just do a refactor, and how to do it.  I suppose P.SE may not be the best forum for my specific inquiry, because it addresses the question from very abstract levels.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/when-is-a-big-rewrite-the-answer#161912 may help but I do not know what they mean by "re-engineer", and I can't make comment w/o having reputation of 50.

Comment: @Dennis Re-engineer, in context, essentially means re-factoring.

Comment: related: [What is the most effective way to add functionality to unfamiliar, structurally unsound code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/135311/31260)

Answer (score 3):

> But doing this will not address things like unit testing, dependency injection, modern framework principles, and so on.

Why not?
You do not need to unit test everything - just around what you change/refactor. And if you test that, you'll progressively add mocks and DI.

I strongly recommend Michael Feather's book: [Working effectively with legacy code](http://www.informit.com/store/working-effectively-with-legacy-code-9780131177055?aid=15d186bd-1678-45e9-8ad3-fe53713e811b), as it describes that problem and solutions quite well.

Comment: My issue right now is that we have a complex interface for product X that has its features selected via menus, a complex computation with temporary variables follows, and a PDF is created.  We are adding a similar product Y that has different parameters and drawings. Easiest thing is to copy files for X into files for Y and go over the code that is relevant and customize things to Y as needed.  When it comes to DI, mocks, and testing,... I guess in this case I just don't see or know how I would do it.  We want to migrate to ZF2 eventually, but I don't see how, the way it's going now.

Comment: Question: what will I gain from reading the book and applying the principles from it?  Suppose I decompose and decouple and refactor the code, add unit tests, and make things object-oriented. I am sure that will take time. But in the end, will it have proper architecture?  Will it be any closer to using a framework such as ZF2 as was the initial intent?  I am concerned that we will end up with some kind of a better code base, but not sure if it will get me to our original intent of using ZF2 (which uses a host of modern OO development principles).  I suppose this will require further analysis.

Comment: Yes, or at least you will be in a position where such changes are possible because you now have an army of tests making sure you do not regress, and code locality is better understood. What prevents change (big or small) is not so much repairing collateral damage than the risk not knowing what the damage is and finding out too late (unhappy customers). The idea is that you build your safety net as you introduce (minor) changes, and that net allows you to make increasingly bigger changes with an acceptable level of risk.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in a similar situation, if well in a completely distinct technology stack, and in my case (and I guess that also in yours) it is quite obvious that a whole rewriting of production code is not an option, due to practical limitations. That makes the most sense is taking it in small steps. When you are required to introduce a new feature, you do it in a more manageable way; when you have to modify an existing module/class/method/whatever, you take the opportunity and refactor it. Always try to end up with a better code, if perhaps at the expense of reducing your velocity a little in order to get some slack to pay your debt. Also, if you can silently introduce a framework that can be helpful in the long run, while coexisting with the current mud, consider it.

Answer (score 0):

Duplication itself is not a problem - it's a way to get quick result. You just need to remember that you have technological debt and allocate time to generalize your code in the future.

What do you mean by `going forwards is painful` - are you planning something big or it's just additional features? There is only one reason for rewriting everything - the case when architecture of your current applicaiton doesn't fit your future development.

Once I had a project that I was developing for several months and it wasn't in particular 'dirty'. I also did unit testing. And then requirement changed and it took me two more months to understand that I have to change architecture. After I realised it I spend 3 weeks to completely rewrite that service - it was active development but I knew what to do.

I think your case is different - you just need to spend more time on cleaning. Start from small things. During next bugfix or implementation of a new feature don't jump right into development. Spend some time on cleaning. Take a rule to slightly improve any code that you touch. Of course without unit tests it's risky - and you will understand it very quickly so next time you will have more insentive to write unit tests.

At the same time you need to start thinking about high level design so you can start generalizing and decomposing system. Strictly speaking this is not refactoring. People tend to misuse this term.

Comment: Duplication itself **is** one of the biggest problems, indeed. It favors and is favored by design decay.

Comment: `going forwards is painful` - implementing new features the way things are now is painful (involves tracing through a lot of bad code, functions, files to get a grasp of what is going on).  Refactoring is painful in a similar way (may mean creating our own haphazard framework somehow).  I don't know how to port this into ZF2.  It will involve re-architecture that we are thinking of a complete rewrite.  So painful in a sense that the project is so big and entangled that unraveling it properly will take a long and tedious time, while our main customer will not just sit there waiting on us.